# Java drawstring working fine in earlier part of the code to count points but doesn't work when to show game over

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am coding a snake game in Java and the code is almost done expect one final a part i have an issue of drawstring not working in a later part of the code but works fine in earlier part like.

I use drawstring to implement a counter that counts points, but I do the same in an if statement when the snake collides with itself but then the text simply isn't showing. Of course it works when moving the code up.

```
public class Game   {
    public static  void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame b = new JFrame("Snake");
        b.setBounds(300,60,905,705);
        b.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        b.setResizable(false);
        Snake snake = new Snake();
        b.setVisible(true);
        b.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        b.add(snake);
    }
}
```

```
public class Snake extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1 L;
    private int[] snakeXlength = new int[750];
    private int[] snakeYlength = new int[750];
    private int[] foodXpos ={20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200,220,240,260,280,300,320,340,360,380,400,420,440,460,480,500,520,540,560,580,600,620,640};
    private int[] foodYpos = {20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200,220,240,260,280,300,320,340,360,380,400,420,440,460,480,500,520,540,560,580,600}; 

    private boolean right = true;
    private boolean left = false;
    private boolean up = false;
    private boolean down = false;
    private boolean over = false;
    private Random random = new Random();
    private int xPos = random.nextInt(32);
    private int yPos = random.nextInt(30);
    private Timer timer;
    private int snakeDelay = 100;
    private int points = 0;
    private int moves = 0;
    private int lengtOfSnake = 3;

    public Snake() {
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        timer = new Timer(snakeDelay, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        // super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 900, 900);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawRect(20, 20, 864, 624);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(21, 21, 863, 623);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        g.drawString("Score: " + points, 400, 15);

        // ******* this counts the score ****
        if (moves == 0) {
            snakeXlength[2] = 60;
            snakeXlength[1] = 80;
            snakeXlength[0] = 100;
            snakeYlength[2] = 100;
            snakeYlength[1] = 100;
            snakeYlength[0] = 100;
        }
        for (int a = 0; a < lengtOfSnake; a++) {
            if (a == 0 && right) {
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.fillRect(snakeXlength[a], snakeYlength[a], 20, 20);
            }
            if (a == 0 && left) {
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.fillRect(snakeXlength[a], snakeYlength[a], 20, 20);
            }
            if (a == 0 && down) {
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.fillRect(snakeXlength[a], snakeYlength[a], 20, 20);
            }
            if (a == 0 && up) {
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.fillRect(snakeXlength[a], snakeYlength[a], 20, 20);
            }
            if (a != 0) {
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g.fillOval(snakeXlength[a], snakeYlength[a], 17, 17);
            }
        }

        if ((foodXpos[xPos] == snakeXlength[0]) && (foodYpos[yPos] == snakeYlength[0])) {
            points++;
            lengtOfSnake++;
            xPos = random.nextInt(32);
            yPos = random.nextInt(30);
        }

        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.fillRect(foodXpos[xPos], foodYpos[yPos], 20, 20);
        g.dispose();

        for (int b = 1; b < lengtOfSnake; b++) {
            if (snakeXlength[b] == snakeXlength[0] && snakeYlength[0] == snakeYlength[b]) {
                right = false;
                left = false;
                up = false;
                down = false;
                over = true;
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.setFont(new Font("game over", Font.BOLD, 20));
                g.drawString("Game over", 300, 300);
                g.drawString("press space bar to restart.", 300, 350);
                thiss is meant to show off game over text.
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            points = 0;
            moves = 0;
            lengtOfSnake = 3;
            over = false;
            repaint();
            xPos = random.nextInt(32);
            yPos = random.nextInt(30);
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && over != true) {
            moves++;
            right = true;
            if (left != true) {
                right = true;
            } else {
                right = false;
                left = true;
            }
            down = false;
            up = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && over != true) {
            moves++;
            left = true;
            if (right != true) {
                left = true;
            } else {
                left = false;
                right = true;
            }
            down = false;
            up = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP && over != true) {
            moves++;
            up = true;
            if (down != true) {
                up = true;
            } else {
                up = false;
                down = true;
            }
            left = false;
            right = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN && over != true) {
            moves++;
            down = true;
            if (up != true) {
                down = true;
            } else {
                up = true;
                down = false;
            }
            left = false;
            right = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        timer.start();
        if (right) {
            for (int r = lengtOfSnake - 1; r >= 0; r--) {
                snakeYlength[r + 1] = snakeYlength[r];
            }
            for (int r = lengtOfSnake; r >= 0; r--) {
                if (r == 0) {
                    snakeXlength[r] = snakeXlength[r] + 20;
                } else {
                    snakeXlength[r] = snakeXlength[r - 1];
                }
                if (snakeXlength[r] > 860) {
                    snakeXlength[r] = 20;
                }
            }
            repaint();
        }
        if (left) {
            for (int r = lengtOfSnake - 1; r >= 0; r--) {
                snakeYlength[r + 1] = snakeYlength[r];
            }
            for (int r = lengtOfSnake; r >= 0; r--) {
                if (r == 0) {
                    snakeXlength[r] = snakeXlength[r] - 20;
                } else {
                    snakeXlength[r] = snakeXlength[r - 1];
                }
                if (snakeXlength[r] < 20) {
                    snakeXlength[r] = 860;
                }
            }
            repaint();
        }
        if (up) {
            for (int r = lengtOfSnake - 1; r >= 0; r--) {
                snakeXlength[r + 1] = snakeXlength[r];
            }
            for (int r = lengtOfSnake; r >= 0; r--) {
                if (r == 0) {
                    snakeYlength[r] = snakeYlength[r] - 20;
                } else {
                    snakeYlength[r] = snakeYlength[r - 1];
                }
                if (snakeYlength[r] < 20) {
                    snakeYlength[r] = 620;
                }
            }
            repaint();
        }
        if (down) {
            for (int r = lengtOfSnake - 1; r >= 0; r--) {
                snakeXlength[r + 1] = snakeXlength[r];
            }
            for (int r = lengtOfSnake; r >= 0; r--) {
                if (r == 0) {
                    snakeYlength[r] = snakeYlength[r] + 20;
                } else {
                    snakeYlength[r] = snakeYlength[r - 1];
                }
                if (snakeYlength[r] > 620) {
                    snakeYlength[r] = 20;
                }
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you commenting out the `super.paint(g);` method call? You should be overriding paintComponent, not paint, and should be calling the super.paintComponent method. Also, why are you disposing of the Graphics object, g? This is dangerous code.

Comment: super.paint(g) is not used

Comment: You are wrong -- you should always call the super's painting method. But your main problem is your calling `g.dispose()`. You should *never* dispose of a Graphics object given to you by the Swing graphics engine, and only dispose one created by yourself.

Comment: Please read: [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html): introductory tutorial to Swing graphics

Comment: My bad, if overriding paint, call super.paint. If overriding paintComponent, call super.paintComponent. Almost always, it is better to do the latter, override paintComponent.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels is the issue caused by me accidently calling override? dispose*